# Javascript - Using functions within objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I am trying to use the move methods in each of the candy objects all at once, but I had a problem: it was using the same deltaX and deltaY for all of them, no matter what I set them each to individually. I have been trying to find out a way to make it so that it would be individual for each object, but I haven't found a way to yet. I was wondering if you guys had a solution.

The Candy function:

```
Candy = function(img, location, canvas) {
    self = {}
    self.image = new Image()
    self.image.src = img
    self.location = {x: location.x, y: location.y}
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.draw = function() {
        self.canvas.drawImage(this.image, this.location.x, this.location.y, 132.4, 132.4)
    }
    self.move = function(FPS, seconds, location) {
        var object = this
        object.frames = FPS * seconds
        object.deltaX = (location.x - this.location.x) / frames
        object.deltaY = (location.y - this.location.y) / frames
        object.counter = 0
        var i = setInterval(function() {
            object.location.x += object.deltaX
            object.location.y += object.deltaY
            object.counter++
            draw()
            if(object.counter >= object.frames)
                clearInterval(i)
        }, 1000 / FPS)
    }
    self.image.onload = function() {
        Candy.list.push(self)
        Candy.queue.splice(0, 1)

        if(Candy.queue.length == 0)
            draw()
        else
            Candy(Candy.queue[0].img, Candy.queue[0].location, Candy.queue[0].canvas)
    }
}
Candy.list = []
Candy.queue = []
```

Where I initiate the movement:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Candy.list.length; i++) {
  var candy = Candy.list[i]
  var x = i < 4 ? width / 5 : 7 * (width / 5)
  var y = candy.location.y
  candy.move(30, 3, {x: x, y: y})
}
```

Where I initialize the candy objects:

```
Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy.png", location: {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: height / 10}, canvas: canvasContext})
    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy2.png", location: {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: 3 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})
    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy3.png", location: {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: 5 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})
    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy4.png", location: {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: 7 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})

    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy2.png", location: {x: width / 2, y: 1 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})
    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy4.png", location: {x: width / 2, y: 3 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})
    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy5.jpg", location: {x: width / 2, y: 5 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})
    Candy.queue.push({img: "client/img/candy.png", location: {x: width / 2, y: 7 * (height / 10)}, canvas: canvasContext})


    Candy(Candy.queue[0].img, Candy.queue[0].location, Candy.queue[0].canvas)
```

The draw function:

```
function draw() {
colorRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'white');
colorText("Player 1", 0.02, 0.05, "black", "40px Comic Sans");
colorText("Player 2", 0.88, 0.05, "black", "40px Comic Sans");

if(!gameStarted) {
    if(player1.ready)
        colorText("Ready", 0.02, 0.09, "green", "20px Comic Sans");
    else
        colorText("Not Ready", 0.02, 0.09, "red", "20px Comic Sans");
    if(player2.ready)
        colorText("Ready", 0.88, 0.09, "green", "20px Comic Sans");
    else
        colorText("Not Ready", 0.88, 0.09, "red", "20px Comic Sans");
    if(player1.ready && player2.ready)
        colorText("Press a button to start the game!", 0.32, 0.5, "black", "40px Comic Sans")
}else{
    for(var i = 0; i < Candy.list.length; i++) {
        Candy.list[i].draw()
    }
    if(decision1 != null) {
        var color
        if(decision1 == "Share")
            color = 'green'
        else
            color = 'red'
        colorText(decision1, 0.02, 0.15, color, "40px Comic Sans");
    }
    if(decision2 != null) {
        var color
        if(decision2 == "Share")
            color = 'green'
        else
            color = 'red'
        colorText(decision2, 0.02, 0.15, color, "40px Comic Sans");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Stack snippet is for **running code** only. I just edited your question for plain code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are never creating a Candy object. This can be easily seen by running `console.log(Candy.list[0] instanceof Candy)` (this will print `false`).

To create a Candy object you must use the `new` keyword.

I have edited your code to insert new Candy objects into the queue. First off, instead of creating a new object like you did with `{}`, your constructor must use the `this` keyword to refer to itself:

```
Candy = function(img, location, canvas) {
    var self = this;
    self.image = new Image()
    self.image.src = img
    self.location = {x: location.x, y: location.y}
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.draw = function() {
        self.canvas.drawImage(self.image, self.location.x, self.location.y, 132.4, 132.4)
    }
    self.move = function(FPS, seconds, location) {
        self.frames = FPS * seconds
        self.deltaX = (location.x - self.location.x) / self.frames
        self.deltaY = (location.y - self.location.y) / self.frames
        self.counter = 0
        var i = setInterval(function() {
            self.location.x += self.deltaX
            self.location.y += self.deltaY
            self.counter++
            draw()
            if(self.counter >= self.frames)
                clearInterval(i)
        }, 1000 / FPS)
    }
    self.image.onload = function() {
        Candy.list.push(self)
        Candy.queue.splice(Candy.queue.indexOf(self), 1)

        if(Candy.queue.length === 0)
            draw()
    }
}
Candy.list = []
Candy.queue = []
```

Initialize code - now with the `new` keyword:

```
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy.png", {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: height / 10}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy2.png", {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: 3 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy3.png", {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: 5 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy4.png", {x: 2 * (width / 5), y: 7 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy2.png", {x: width / 2, y: 1 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy4.png", {x: width / 2, y: 3 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy5.jpg", {x: width / 2, y: 5 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
Candy.queue.push(new Candy("client/img/candy.png", {x: width / 2, y: 7 * (height / 10)}, canvasContext))
```

The movement code doesn't need changing.

Comment: This did not work. I tried changing my code to yours, but it set me back to one of my initial issues with my code. When this code is ran, it only draws and creates that last piece of candy made. I will show my draw code just in case you would need to see it.

Comment: The problem is with the image.onload. When the image finally loads, it take all the properties of the last created piece of candy.

Comment: Alright, so they got drawn just fine, but their location get set to NaN when I try to use the move() method.

Comment: Added `self.` to `frames`. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is var object = this;

You are manipulating the same object reference on each call.

You maybe could try something like

```
var object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this);
```

to clone the object.

Edit: 
Or better

```
var object = Object.assign({}, this);
```

to keep the functions.

Comment: I tried this, but this just caused all of their locations to continue to be NaN.